# How to remove "PHPSESSID" cookie on client browser immediately after any product added to cart in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have an issue with "PHPSESSID" cookie in adding some products to cart in woocommerce. It store some variations of product in "PHPSESSID" cookie and when adding another product to cart it makes some conflicts.

Comment: your doing something wrong if you need this, its just the session cookie. you shouldn't be putting anything in it at all

Comment: You don't store anything in the cookie itself, you store it in the `$_SESSION` array, which will store the value on the server, and the only thing the user should get is the PHPSESSID cookie containing the session ID and nothing else.

Comment: I have to using a plugin to able users upload images for every product and the plugin store uploaded images information in "PHPSESSID". It should be remove it every time after adding product to cart to upload new files for other product but it doesn't.

Comment: ok, I think you are right. should to find another solution.